# SQLServer select common element

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hopefully a fairly simple bit of SQL, I have a table with two columns, street and city.  Given a list of 3 street names, how do I select the city which is common to the streets?

For example.

```
Street     City
------     ----
1st St     NYC
2nd St     NYC
3rd St     NYC
1st St     SF
1st St     LA
etc St     XX
```

If I have "1st St", "2nd St" and "3rd St", which query returns "NYC"?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select t.city
from table t
where t.street in ('1st st', '2nd st', '3rd st')
group by t.city
having count(distinct t.street) = 3;
```

This is an example of a set-within-sets query, where you are looking for sets of things (streets) for another thing (cities).  `Group by` and `having` is a very flexible way of addressing this type of problem.